# Python: Extracting Sentences From Line - Regex Needed Based on Criteria

Tags: python, regex

Somewhat of a python/programming newbie here...

I am trying to come up with a regex that can handle extracting sentences from a line in a text file, and then appending them to a list. The code:

```
import re

txt_list = []

with open('sample.txt', 'r') as txt:
    patt = r'.*}[.!?]\s?\n?|.*}.+[.!?]\s?\n?'
    read_txt = txt.readlines()

    for line in read_txt:
        if line == "\n":
            txt_list.append("\n")
        else: 
            found = re.findall(patt, line)
            for f in found:
                txt_list.append(f)


for line in txt_list:
    if line == "\n":
        print "newline"
    else:
        print line
```

Printed Output as per last 5 lines of above code:

```
{Hello there|Hello|Howdy} Dr. Munchauson you {gentleman|fine fellow}! 
What {will|shall|should} we {eat|have} for lunch? Peas by the {thousand|hundred|1000} said Dr. Munchauson; {that|is} what he said.

newline
I am the {very last|last} sentence for this {instance|example}.
```

The contents of 'sample.txt':

```
{Hello there|Hello|Howdy} Dr. Munchauson you {gentleman|fine fellow}! What {will|shall|should} we {eat|have} for lunch? Peas by the {thousand|hundred|1000} said Dr. Munchauson; {that|is} what he said.

I am the {very last|last} sentence for this {instance|example}.
```

I have been playing around with the regex for a couple of hours now and I cannot seem to crack it. As it stands the regex does not match at the end of `for lunch?`. Therefore these 2 sentences `What {will|shall|should} we {eat|have} for lunch? Peas by the {thousand|hundred|1000} said Dr. Munchauson; {that|is} what he said.` are not separated; which is what I want.

A few important details for the regex:

- Every sentence will always end in a period, exclamation mark or question mark
- Every sentence will always contain at least 1 pair of curly brackets '{}' with some words in. **Also there will be no misleading '.' after the last bracket in every sentence. Therefore `Dr.` will always be before the last pair of curly brackets in each sentence**. This is why I have attempted to base my regex around using '}'. This way I can avoid using the exceptions approach, of creating exceptions for such grammar as `Dr.`, `Jr.`, `approx.` and so on. For each file I run this code on, I personally make sure there is no 'misleading period' after the last '}' in any sentence.

The output that I want is this:

```
{Hello there|Hello|Howdy} Dr. Munchauson you {gentleman|fine fellow}! 
What {will|shall|should} we {eat|have} for lunch?
Peas by the {thousand|hundred|1000} said Dr. Munchauson; {that|is} what he said.

newline
I am the {very last|last} sentence for this {instance|example}.
```

Comment: In this "{Hello there|Hello|Howdy} Dr. Munchauson you {gentleman|fine fellow}!" there is misleading "." here.The First period is also after the last bracket in this "sentence" : "{Hello there|Hello|Howdy} Dr."

Comment: In that sentence, the '!' is the end of the sentence, and the '!' comes after the last '}' in that sentence. As I explain in the OP, a sentence can end with either a period, exclamation or a question mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most intuitive solution I've got is this. Essentially, you need to treat the `Dr.` and `Mr.` tokens as atoms in their own right.

```
patt = r'(?:Dr\.|Mr\.|.)*?[.!?]\s?\n?'
```

Broken down, its says:

> Find me the least number of `Mr.`s, `Dr.`s or any character up to a puncuation mark followed by a zero or one spaces which is followed by zero or one new lines.

When used on this sample.txt (I added a line):

```
{Hello there|Hello|Howdy} Dr. Munchauson you {gentleman|fine fellow}! What {will|shall|should} we {eat|have} for lunch? Peas by the {thousand|hundred|1000} said Dr. Munchauson; {that|is} what he said.

But there are no {misters|doctors} here good sir! Help us if there is an emergency.

I am the {very last|last} sentence for this {instance|example}.
```

It gives:

```
{Hello there|Hello|Howdy} Dr. Munchauson you {gentleman|fine fellow}!
What {will|shall|should} we {eat|have} for lunch?
Peas by the {thousand|hundred|1000} said Dr. Munchauson; {that|is} what he said.

newline
But there are no {misters|doctors} here good sir!
Help us if there is an emergency.

newline
I am the {very last|last} sentence for this {instance|example}.
```

Comment: Hi there, I was really hoping to avoid using exceptions in that way because I will run this code on many text files. So there could be many exceptions such as `Sr.`, `approx.`, `info.`, `e.t.c` and so on. The only thing I now for certain is that there will be no `.` after the last closing curly bracket `}` in every sentence - unless of course that `.` actually is the end of the sentence.

Comment: I don't think you can have a generic one. You can say the only periods after the last curly bracket won't be abbreviations, but how can a regex know the difference between `} Dr. ` and `} said.`? They are both letters followed by a period. We could say that the former has a captial letter, but that precludes `approx.`, `info.`, `e.t.c`, etc... Without declaring whats a "valid" period in a sentence, I don't think you can do what you are asking.

Comment: I see, and I was hoping that my regex skills weren't quite good enough for the task. Ok, I guess I will yield to the substantial exceptions approach. Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: Since this answer and the one given by @aelfric5578 were both very useful, it was not easy figuring out which answer to mark as accepted. Essentially I accept them both. However I have to go with this one because it established that regex is not going to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you're don't mind adding a dependency, the NLTK library has a `sent_tokenize` function that should do what you need, though I'm not entirely sure whether the curly brackets will interfere.

The paper describing the method NLTK used is 40+ pages long.  Detecting sentence boundaries isn't a trivial task.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was aware that `sent_tokenize` exists, although I had not given it a shot yet. I was hoping to make my script here work off the back of a curly bracket and regex, but looks like it ain't happening. I just tried `sent_tokenize` on several files that contain these curly brackets and it split all the sentences accurately, so I think I will stick with it. It don't preserve the newlines in the way I want but I can work a little code out for that. Cheers

Comment: Rather than tokenizing the whole block of text, you can feed each line to `sent_tokenize` separately.  As long as you don't expect sentences to go beyond one line in the source file, that should let you preserve newlines the way you want.